# How to parse standard SQL (BigQuery) to get input columns and output columns

Tags: google-bigquery, abstract-syntax-tree, sql-parser

We're building a data warehouse in BigQuery where we generate a large amount of data marts using standard sql statements. These can be quite large and complex. To track data lineage across a chain of dependencies, we'd like to automatically parse the SQL statements and get all the output columns, matched up with the input table.column(s).

Simple example:

`SELECT t1.a, t2.b, t1.a + t2.b AS c
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.a = t2.a`

Should end up giving us:

`Input     Output
table1.a   a
table2.b   b
table1.a   c
table1.b   c`

We've tried using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sql-parser, but it comes up short in some of our complex scenarios.

Is there any library available in any language which supports parsing a SQL statement and returning the AST for the full standard SQL grammar?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [google/zetasql](https://github.com/google/zetasql), which is what BigQuery uses for parsing StandardSQL.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I'm looking into that. It is however not in a very user-friendly state. I'm currently getting assistance from the very helpful contributors to get it up and running.

Comment: Sorry to hear that it is not in a user-friendly state. It is still your best bet than any other solution for its first-party nature.

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase that. It is in a perfectly fine state, but it requires some development to get to where I want, and the documentation is somewhat lacking at this point.

Comment: @Bjoern I have the same usecase, can you guide me in a proper direction with some rough steps to get this to work?